# Creating a retention variable in R Based on the value of X in year t+1

Tags: r, retention

I want to create a retention in R, the data looks as follows:

ID is an individual, who participated in year t.

`Albert.Heijn` is 1 if the individual visited Albert Heijn.

`Albert.Heijnv1-7` are customer satisfaction measurements.

If `Albert.Heijn` is `NA`, the individual did not visited the company in that year, thus the satisfaction measurements are `NA`

[image]

Now I need to create a retention variable, probably using a `for loop`. Because `ID 14401` = retention for 2012, because `Albert.Heijn` in 2013 = 1. However, this same person does not get retention in 2013, because 2014 is missing. 
In 2015 again, retention will be 1 because `Albert.Heijn` = 1 in 2016. For 2016 retention will be 0 because no data of 2017 is available.

Finally, 2016 and 2013 should afterward be deleted, since retention cannot be measured if there is no observation of a consecutive year.

This needs to be done for 180+ different companies.

Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your example using `dput` instead of images and the expected output

Comment: if your data is very big use: dput(head(YourData))

Comment: @MelvinBredewold you can create a sample data frame that has the important variables.

Comment: This is an example of a small part of the data using dput, where 1 = visited company X, 0= not visited 

> dput(head(Book2))
structure(list(ID = c(13302, 13302, 14401, 14401, 14401, 14401
), Jaar = c(2012, 2015, 2012, 2013, 2015, 2016), `Albert Heijn` = c(1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1), Aldi = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Bas van der Heijden` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Boni = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), C1000 = c(1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0), Coop = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), Deen = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), DekaMarkt = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Digros = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution. You will need to create also a loop for the `ID`.

**Sample data**

```
df <- data.frame("ID" = c(1,1,2,2,2,2), "Year" = c(2012, 2015,2012,2013,2015,2016), "AH" = c(1, NA, 1,1,1,1))
```

**Code for `ID == 2`**

```
current_year <- df[df$ID == 2, "Year"]
n <- length(current_year)
i = 0
df$retention <- 0
while(i<n){
  i = i + 1

  df_temp <- subset(df, df$Year == (current_year[i]+1) & df$ID == 2 )
  n_temp <- nrow(df_temp)
  if(n_temp>0)
  if(df[df$Year == (current_year[i]+1), "ID" ] == 2 & df[df$Year == (current_year[i]+1), "AH"] == 1)
  {
    df[df$Year == current_year[i] & df$ID == 2, "retention"] <- 1
  }


}
```

**EDIT - More general code**

If you want to generalize it for all `ID`, you need to create a list of unique IDs, count the number of IDs and do a while loop. Code below

```
df <- data.frame("ID" = c(1,1,2,2,2,2), "Year" = c(2012, 2015,2012,2013,2015,2016), "AH" = c(1, NA, 1,1,1,1))

ID_list <- unique(df$ID)

n_ID <- length(ID_list)

j = 0

while(j < n_ID)
{
  j = j + 1
current_year <- df[df$ID == ID_list[j], "Year"]
n <- length(current_year)
i = 0
df$retention <- 0
while(i<n){
  i = i + 1

  df_temp <- subset(df, df$Year == (current_year[i]+1) & df$ID == ID_list[j] )
  n_temp <- nrow(df_temp)
  if(n_temp>0)
  if(df[df$Year == (current_year[i]+1), "ID" ] == ID_list[j] & df[df$Year == (current_year[i]+1), "AH"] == 1)
  {
    df[df$Year == current_year[i] & df$ID == ID_list[j], "retention"] <- 1
  }


}
}
```

Comment: Hi Barbara, thank you for the code, the loop works and gives me the right outcomes concerning retention! One more little question, how can I extend this loop to more observations and more variables?

Comment: @MelvinBredewold I have edited my answer with a generalization for the `ID` column. If you want to add more variables, you can add them in the same loop for the retention, since the number of rows will be the same regardless of the variable/column.

Comment: I came across the following error as i try to implement in on all Observations, without adding any other variables:

Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, df$Year == current_year[i] & df$ID ==  : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames
In addition: Warning message:
In if (df[df$Year == (current_year[i] + 1), "ID"] == ID_list[j] &  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Retention = 0 for all obs and df_temp gives 1 obs for all variables

Comment: Try substituting the`if statement` with this code `df[df$Jaar == current_year[i] & df$ID == ID_list[j], "retention"] <- ifelse(df[df$Jaar == (current_year[i]+1), "ID" ] == ID_list[j] & df[df$Jaar == (current_year[i]+1), "AH"] == 1, 1, df$retention)`

Comment: thank you for the code. I eventually solved it with the following loop: 

ID_list <- unique(df$ID)

n_ID <- length(ID_list)

j = 0
df$AHr <- 0
while(j < n_ID)
{
  j = j + 1
  current_year <- subset(df,subset=ID==ID_list[j],select="Year")
    #df[df$ID == ID_list[j], "Year"]
  n <- nrow(current_year)
  i = 0
  
  while(i<n){
    i = i + 1
    
    df_temp <- subset(df,subset=(Year==(current_year[i,1]+1))&

Comment: ID==ID_list[j])
      #subset(df, df$Year == (current_year[i]+1) & df$ID == ID_list[j] )
    n_temp <- nrow(df_temp)
    if(n_temp>0)
      if((subset(df,subset=(Year==(current_year[i,1]+1))&(ID==ID_list[j]),select="AH")==1)&(subset(df,subset=(Year==(current_year[i,1]))&(ID==ID_list[j]),select="AH")==1))
      #if(df[df$Year == (current_year[i,1]+1), "ID" ] == ID_list[j] & (df[df$Year == (current_year[i,1]+1), "AH"] == 1))

Comment: {
        #subset(df,subset=(Year==current_year[i,1])&(ID==ID_list[j]),select="AHr")
        indx=which((df$Year == current_year[i,1]) & (df$ID == ID_list[j]))
        df[indx, "AHr"] <- 1
        #print("yuhu")
      }
    
    
  }
}